# Polly.js - Is it possible to create 1 Polly recording that can be used across multiple tests?

Tags: testing, jestjs, pollyjs

I'd like to know if it's possible to create 1 Polly recording that can be reused across multiple tests. Right now each test creates it's own recording file.

https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/README for reference.

Comment: Provide your code under test and what you have tried. The question needs more focus. Otherwise, it will be voted to close.   The readme content is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching through their documentation there does appear to be a way to accomplish this with the recordingName method, hopefully this helps if anyone else is using Polly and wants to de-clutter their test files:  https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/server/route-handler?id=recordingname

Answer (score 1):

PollyJS has a configuration option named [recordingName](https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/server/route-handler?id=recordingname) which specifies the filepath where the HAR file will be saved.

> Note:  The provided name is sanitized as well as postfixed with a GUID. The postfixed value is hashed using the `recordingName`, so it will remain constant.

Here's an example of configuring the `recordingName` property:

```
new Polly('MyStoreCms/ShoppingCart', {
  /* ... */
});
```

With this configuration, the directory structure in your recordings directory will be as follows:

```
recordings
  └── MyStoreCms_1234
      └── ShoppingCart_5678
          └── recording.json
```